# Difference between glGetUniformLocation and glGetAttribLocation

Tags: opengl-es

I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0. Apparently you can get the location for any shader variable just using glGetAttribLocation. This means you don't need to use glGetUniformLocation for uniform variables, however you can't do this the other way around. Why is this?

EDIT:

VS:

```c
 uniform mat4 uMvpMat;
 attribute vec4 vPos;
 void main() {
     gl_Position = uMvpMat * vPos;
 }
```

FS:

```c
 precision mediump float;
 uniform vec4 vColor;
 void main() {
     gl_FragColor = vColor;
 }
```

For example, `glGetUniformLocation(programSolidHandle, "vColor")` seems to be equivalent to `glGetAttribLocation(programSolidHandle, "vColor")`. However this doesn't apply for `glGetUniformLocation(programSolidHandle, "vPos")`, which doesn't work.

Comment: Is this true? I thought that `glGetAttribLocation` only returned the location for *attribute* variables, and `glGetUniformLocation` only returned the location for *uniform* variables.

Comment: @DietrichEpp It seems glGetAttribLocation can be used for both, but glGetUniformLocation only for uniform variables

Comment: That's just repeating what you said in the question. Where are you seeing this? Do you have code, or did you read this somewhere?

Comment: @DietrichEpp I have tested it myself on a regular shader, I can put the code here

Comment: @DietrichEpp edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the spec, you can not use glGetAttribLocation to get uniform locations: [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetAttribLocation.xml) (emphasis mine)

> glGetAttribLocation queries the   previously linked program object
> specified by  program for the attribute variable  specified by name
> and returns the index     of the generic vertex attribute that is bound
> to that attribute     variable. If name is a matrix attribute     variable,
> the index of the first column of the matrix is    returned. **If the named
> attribute variable is not an active   attribute** in the specified
> program object or if  name starts with the reserved prefix    "gl_", **a
> value of -1 is returned.**

So, you have discovered a bug in the implementation you are using. It's one of those insidious bugs which appears harmless but actually makes it easier for application developers to write non-portable code.

Comment: @super: What part of "this is a driver bug" did you not understand? The version of OpenGL you use is irrelevant; it's caused by *the driver*. So if you're using the same driver that happens to expose ES 3.0, it's highly likely that it has the same bug. But it's *still a bug*. Stop looking into it and do things correctly.